# Calculate the number of times that cases were out-of-bag (out-of-bag sample size)

Tags: r, random-forest

Breiman (Breiman, L. (2001), Random Forests, Machine Learning 45(1), 5-32) states that *"In each bootstrap training set, about one-third of the instances are left out"*. Providing the following example:

```
library(randomForest)
library(MASS)
data(fgl)
set.seed(17)
table(fgl$type)
model.rf <- randomForest(type ~ ., data = fgl, mtry = 2)
```

how do I define the number of average proportion of out-of-bag cases in the analysis (which corresponds with Breiman´s statement)?

My take on it is to see the average OOB cases per number of trees, from `model.rf$oob.times` diveded by the number of `ntree` and then put that number in relation to the data size aka number of rows/records in the data to see the proportion of OOBs in the whole dataset, hence:

```
sum(model.rf$oob.times)/model.rf$ntree/nrow(fgl)
```

It comes down to 0.3664019 which is somewhat one third and close to another [thread on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173520/random-forests-out-of-bag-sample-size) that states the out-of-bag sample size theoretically (0.3678).

Would this be an accurate answer to my question?

Comment: All three numbers you cite are approximations to $1/e\approx 0.367879$, which is the limiting proportion for large datasets.

Comment: Could you elaborate Dr. Huber, what is meant by "limiting proportion for large datasets"?

Comment: The expected number of instances left out is always a rational number, and therefore never exactly equal to $1/e$, but as the dataset size increases, it approaches $1/e$.  A good search term is [derangement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=derangement).

Comment: Thank you, I understand this RF OOB rule now better. This also speaks in favor of my personal understanding of the issue.