# Does oob error consider all data points

Tags: random-forest

When a random forest model is built, does the out-of-bag error consider all the data points in the set, at the end?

I know that it is basically asking decision trees to make predictions on data points that was not part of their training data. However when this exercise is completed, will all the data points in the set be accounted for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forest consists of a large number of trees. A random forests consists of a large number of decision or regression trees. Each of these trees will be grown with a different random set of the data. Thus with a sufficiently large number of trees all the data will be accounted for in the construction of the forest but not in the construction of each tree.
Obviously there is a chance of a single datapoint not being represented in any of the trees, but every tree will on average contain about two thirds of all the data (cd https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88994/117812 ) and the preset for `ntree` in the `randomforest` package in the `randomForest` R package is 500.